# How can I make SQL Server 2012 truncate insertions if they are too big?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, database-design, sql-server-2012

So I have a `table` with a column of type `VARCHAR (100)` and I'm wondering if there's a way to configure `SQL Server 2012 (T-SQL)` so that if a transaction tries to submit a string of **101+ characters** then it takes the first 100.

Is this possible, or should I be doing the `truncation` in the `C#` side of things ???

Comment: Can you post your `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I'm assuming it's possible to be done DB-side, but it's probably a bad idea. Better to have that in the application layer, otherwise you're going to run into a bug in (lets say) 6 months and have no idea why your DB is randomly corrupting data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, SQL Server will present an error on any attempt to insert more data into a field than it can hold

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

SQL Server will not permit a silent truncation of data just because the column is too small to accept the data. But there are other ways that SQL Server can truncate data that is about to be inserted into a table that will not generate any form of error or warning.

By default, ANSI_WARNINGS are turned on, and certain activities such as creating indexes on computed columns or indexed views require that they be turned on. But if they are turned off, SQL Server will truncate the data as needed to make it fit into the column. The ANSI_WARNINGS setting for a session can be controlled by

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS { ON|OFF }
```

Unlike with an insert into a table, SQL Server will quietly cut off data that is being assigned to a variable, regardless of the status of ANSI_WARNINGS. For instance:

```
declare @smallString varchar(5)
declare @testint int
set @smallString = 'This is a long string'
set @testint = 123.456
print @smallString
print @testint
```

Results is:

```
This 
123
```

This can occasionally show itself in subtle ways since passing a value into a stored procedure or function assigns it to the parameter variables and will quietly do a conversion. One method that can help guard against this situation is to give any parameter that will be directly inserted into a table a larger datatype than the target column so that SQL Server will raise the error, or perhaps to then check the length of the parameter and have custom code to handle it when it is too long.

For instance, if a stored procedure will use a parameter to insert data into a table with a column that is varchar(10), make the parameter varchar(15). Then if the data that is passed in is too long for the column, it will rollback and raise a truncation error instead of silently truncating and inserting. Of course, that runs the risk of being misleading to anyone who looks at the stored procedures header information without understanding what was done.

[Source: Silent Truncation of SQL Server Data Inserts](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2857/silent-truncation-of-sql-server-data-inserts/)

Comment: why is this the highest voted response? wtf

Answer (score 2):

Do this on code level. When you are inserting the current field check field length and Substring it.

```
string a = "string with more than 100 symbols";

if(a.Length > 100)
   a = a.Substring(0, 100);
```

After that you are adding a as sql parameter to the insert query.

The other way is to do it in the query, but again I don't advice you to do that.

```
INSERT INTO Table1('YourColumn') VALUES(LEFT(RTRIM(stringMoreThan100symbols), 100))
```

LEFT is cutting the string and RTRIM is performing Trim operation of the string.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the length of the `VARCHAR` columns so that I don't have the "magic number" 100 floating around?

Comment: @user5648283: you can find the [Column Size and dataType from getschemaTable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17211438/3796048)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make the application side responsible for validating the input before calling any `DB` operation.

SQL Server silently truncates any `varchars` you specify as `stored procedure parameters` to the length of the `varchar`. So you should try considering `stored procedures` for you requirements. So it will get handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have entity classes (not necessarily from EF) you can use [StringLength(your field length)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to do this.